# Pushpin Web-Sockets over http

Tags: node.js, websocket, real-time, pushpin

I am trying to test [pushpin](https://pushpin.org) for realtime APIs 
succeeded in implementing both Server sent events and normal Web-Sockets.
using Node JS & HAPI
But when it came to Web-Sockets over HTTP , nothing worked
I tried express-grip [Module](https://github.com/fanout/express-grip)
also grip & hapi-plugin-websocket 
nothing worked.

when i tried there one and only php example, it failed on both normal websockets and websockets over http .
Video[Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G9vVoN2tyeM&t=76s)
Any Clues ?! 
[Full Ref.](https://pushpin.org/docs/usage/#subscribing) 
Notes ::

1. I am running a cloned version of pushpin
2. My config/routes file is * localhost:3000,overhttp

Comment: it didn't take that long,the problem was overhttp
it was supposed to be over_http
`* localhost:3000,over_http`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it didn't take that long,the problem was overhttp it was supposed to be over_http * localhost:3000,over_http